# Android ImageView md5 different from original image

Tags: android, image, imageview, md5

I have an image downloaded from an API. I set the image to the imageview using `imageView.setImageUri(uri)`.

The problem happened when I check for the color of a certain pixel of the image which is slightly different from the color on the original image. Later on I check the md5 of the original image is different with what the imageview has.

Is this a correct behaviour of Android? How can I make sure the color of the imageview is the same as the original image?

Comment: are you doing encoding, or scaling, or reducing size, after download the image?

Comment: no, I check my md5 after downloading and it is the same as the one in the server. My suspection is that the image view does decode the file to bitmap.